# Internship in Netherlands with French visa

Tags: visa, france, taxes, netherlands, internship

I am non-EU citizen with a French student visa, I got an offer to do a six months fully remote internship for a Netherlands company, thus I’ll be living in France the whole time. In the case, do I still need to obtain any documents from Dutch government ?

And it’s a paid internship, will I pay my taxes in France or Netherlands ?

Comment: If the Dutch company has previously had a remote intern (i.e., not from the Netherlands), the company may be able to offer you further information about these issues.